# Player don't move slowly ( smoothly)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a question please in my game when i write "LEFT"  in a InputField and click on a UI Button the cube move "LEFT" and eat coins(the same for up, down , right) my problem is when i wrote this code below the player moved but not slowly more like disappear than appear in the position that declare it

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField mainInputField;
    //public float speed;

    public GameObject Player;
    public Button Click_me;

    public float smoothing = 1f;
    public Transform TargetRight1;
    public Transform TargetRight2;
    public Transform TargetUP;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    public void SubmitName()
    {
        string[] lines = mainInputField.text.Split('\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lines[i] == "UP")
            {
                // moveUP();
                StartCoroutine(MyCoroutineUP(TargetUP));
            }
            else if (lines[i] == "DOWN")
            {
                //MoveDown();
            }
            else if (lines[i] == "LEFT")
            {
                //MoveLeft();
            }
            else if (lines[i] == "RIGHT")
            {
                StartCoroutine(MyCoroutineUP(TargetRight1));
            }
        }
        // Click_me.interactable = false;
    }

    IEnumerator MyCoroutineUP(Transform target)
    {
        while (Vector3.Distance(Player.transform.position, target.position) > 0.05f)
        {
            Player.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Player.transform.position, target.position, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);       
        }

        yield return null;
    }  
}
```

know if i put the `yield return null;`  inside the while loop like this

```
while (Vector3.Distance(Player.transform.position, target.position) > 0.05f)
{
    Player.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Player.transform.position, target.position, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
    yield return null;
}
```

the player move slowly and get the coins but if i have more than 2 ligne for example i wrote LEFT , UP the while loop won't work properly when i call the function in the first line. sorry for my English

[image: Game image]

Comment: What exactly are your TargetRight, TargetUp? Are they stationary points or are the the positions of some coins?

Comment: TaargetUP , TargetRight are a empty gameobject in a specific position that i want the player to go to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get concurrent Coroutines.

It sounds like what you actually are asking is how to **stack** multiple commands and work them one by one. This gets a bit more complex but sounds like the perfect usecase for a [`Queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1)

```
private readonly Queue<Transform> _commands = new Queue<Transform>();

public void SubmitName()
{
    var lines = mainInputField.text.Split('\n');
    mainInputField.text = "";
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        switch (line)
        {
            case "UP":
                // adds a new item to the end of the Queue
                _commands.Enqueue(TargetUp);
                break;

            case "DOWN":
                _commands.Enqueue(TargetDown);
                break;

            case "LEFT":
                _commands.Enqueue(TargetLeft);
                break;

            case "RIGHT":
                _commands.Enqueue(TargetRight);
                break;
        }
    }

    StartCoroutine(WorkCommands());
}

private IEnumerator WorkCommands()
{
    // block input
    Click_me.interactable = false;

    // run this routine until all commands are handled
    while (_commands.Count > 0)
    {
        // returns the first element and at the same time removes it from the queue
        var target = _commands.Dequeue();

        // you can simply yield another IEnumerator
        // this makes it execute and at the same time waits until it finishes
        yield return MovementCoroutine(target);
    }

    // when done allow input again
    Click_me.interactable = true;
}
```

---

To the lerping itself:

I wouldn't lerp like that. That starts the movement very quick and gets slower in the end but never really reaches the target position. If thats what you want leave it but I would rather recommend doing something like

```
private IEnumerator MovementCoroutine(Transform target)
{
    var startPos = transform.position;
    var targetPos = target.position;

    var timePassed = 0f;

    do
    {
        var lerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, timePassed / smoothing);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, targetPos, lerpFactor);

        timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    while(timePassed < smoothing);

    // just to be sure there is no over or undershooting
    // in the end set the correct target position
    transform.position = targetPos;
}
```

In `smoothing` you would then instead set the time in seconds the lerping should take in total. In my opinion this gives you more control. The [`SmoothStep`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothStep.html) makes the movement still being eased in and out.

If you want you could additionally also take the current distance into account for always making the object move with more or less the same speed regardless how close or far the target position is by adding/changing

```
    var distance = Vector3.Distance(startPos, targetPos);
    var duration = smoothing * distance;

    do
    {
        var lerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, timePassed / duration);

        ...
    }
    while (timePassed < duration);
```

now in `smoothing` you would rather set the time in seconds the object should need to move 1 Unity unit.

---

I don't know your exact setup for the targets ofcourse but this is how it would look like with targets attached to the player (so they move along with it)

[image]

Comment: Good answer, how can you add gif in stackoverflow?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre like any other image as long as it is smaller than 2Mb ;)